# Finding a Compact Subspace to Prove Minimum Point

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $f(x_1,...x_n)=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i}{x_i}$, when $a_i>0$ for all $i$. Show that $f$ has a minimum on the set $A=\{u=(u_1,..u_n)\in \mathbb{R}^n: ||u||=1, \forall i\in[1,n], u_i>0\}$.

Obviously $f$ is continuous on $A$, but $A$ isn't compact, such that Weierstrauss's theorem for multiple dimensions isn't valid, so my thinking is to find a compact subset of $A$, which we can call $B$, and to use Weierstrauss's theorem for multiple dimensions on $B$, and also show that the minimum of $A$ isn't in $B^C$.

My only trouble is figuring out what $B$ should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\exists M\in \mathbb R \quad \text{s.t}\quad B=\{u\in A :f(u)\leq M\} \neq \varnothing$$
Now since $f$ is continues on $A$ and $A$ is a bounded set, $B$ is a compact set.